# How to block UI using pageLoading in jQueryMobile

Tags: user-interface, jquery-mobile, loading, block

Is it possible to block the UI when using `$.mobile.pageLoading(false)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature isn't implemented in jQueryMobile Alpha 1.0a4.1.

I solved the problem adding a overlay div with high enough z-index.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
    $('body').append('<div id="block-ui"></div>');      

    $('#ajax_request').click(function(){        
        $('#block-ui').show();
        $.mobile.pageLoading(false);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#block-ui {
    display: none;
    cursor: wait;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

If you're using using fixed-bars you need to override z-index value:

```
.ui-header-fixed, .ui-footer-fixed {
    z-index: 8 !important;
}
```